# Creating a relationship between two ArrayList objects

Tags: java, collections, relationship

I have two `ArrayLists`, `moviesAvailable` and `moviesRented`, in a class called `Catalogue` and I have another `ArrayList` called `currentlyRented` in a class called `Customer`. I want the `moviesRented` and `currentlyRented` to be associated so that one `Customer` can have many movies rented.

I have the code so that when a customer rents a movie, that movie is removed from the `moviesAvailable` class and addeto the `moviesRented` class. I want each customer to have a `currentlyRented` list.

The `Catalogue` class:

```
private Kiosk kiosk;
private List<Movie> moviesAvailable = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Movie> moviesRented =  new ArrayList<>();
private List<Genre> genres =  new ArrayList<>();

public void rentMovie(int id, String title) {
    Movie mov = movie(title);
    if(mov.hasType(title))
        moviesRented.add(mov);
        moviesAvailable.removeIf(movie -> movie.hasType(title));
        System.out.println("Movie rented.\n");
}
public Movie movie(String title) {
    for(Movie movie : moviesAvailable)
        if(movie.hasType(title))
            return movie;
    return null;
}
public void returnMovie(int id, String title) {
    Movie mov = movie(title);
        moviesRented.removeIf(movie -> movie.hasType(title));
        moviesAvailable.add(mov);
        System.out.println(title + " has been returned.");
}
```

The `Customer` Class:

```
private int ID;
private String name;
private int balance;
private List<Movie> currentlyRented = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Movie> rentingHistory = new ArrayList<>();

public Customer(int ID, String name, int balance) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.name = name;
    this.balance = balance;
}
public boolean hasType(int id) {
    return id == (this.ID);
}
public void movie(int id, String title) {
    Movie movie = movie(title);
        currentlyRented.add(movie);
        rentingHistory.add(movie);
}
public void returnMovie(int id, String title) {
    Movie mov = movie(title);
    if(mov.hasType(title))
        currentlyRented.removeIf(movie -> movie.hasType(title));
}
public Movie movie(String title) {
    for(Movie movie : currentlyRented)
        if(movie.hasType(title))
            return movie;
    return null;
}
public void rents() {
    System.out.println(name + " has the following movies: " );
    System.out.println("Movies currently rented by " + name + ":");
}
```

When I run the full program, what happens is if I enter a customer `id`, and the `title` of the movie, it rents the movie. When I rent another one using a different `id`, once again it rents. However when I enter a customer `id` to return a movie, it lists the movies of both customers.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @Sweeper Every customer accesses the same ```currentlyRented``` list, how can I make it so that each customer has a separate list.

Comment: No they don’t. Each customer does have their own list. The list is not static.

Comment: Your `if(mov.hasType(title))` has no `{ }`, so it affects only 1 line after it. Fix your indentations while at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are duplicating the behavior of renting/returning a movie in both `Customer` and `Catalog`. Choose one, then manage all lists contents from there. Here is an example implementation where `Customer` performs the operations:

```
class Movie {

    String title;

    public Movie(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    // equals, hashCode, toString
}

class Catalog {

    public static final List<Movie> moviesAvailable = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final List<Movie> moviesRented = new ArrayList<>();
}

class Customer {

    private List<Movie> currentlyRented = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Movie> rentingHistory = new ArrayList<>();

    public void rentMovie(String title) {
        Movie movie = new Movie(title);
        if (Catalog.moviesAvailable.remove(movie)) {
            Catalog.moviesRented.add(movie);
            currentlyRented.add(movie);
            System.out.println("Movie " + movie + " was rented to " + this);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Movie " + movie + " is not available");
        }
    }

    public void returnMovie(String title) {
        Movie movie = new Movie(title);
        if (currentlyRented.remove(movie)) {
            rentingHistory.add(movie);
            Catalog.moviesRented.remove(movie);
            Catalog.moviesAvailable.add(movie);
            System.out.println("Movie " + movie + " was returned by " + this);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Movie " + movie + " is not being rented by " + this);
        }
    }
}
```

Since there is only one `Catalog`, either make it a singleton or use the static members approach as demonstrated above (which is simpler). If you are careful, all lists will be correctly synchronized. However, this approach allows the catalog lists to be modified outside of the customer's methods. Then even though `currentlyRented` contains a movie, `Catalog.moviesRented` might not. There are other designs that can eliminate this issue, but this is out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better design to have a Rental class too, that would hold a Movie and a Customer, (or a list of customers if each movie could be rented by more than one customer).
Then your Catalogue class could have a list of Rentals for all Customers, and a list of Movies (all of them, rented or not).
Like this, you could iterate through all the Rentals of your Catalogue class and return only the ones applicable to a specific Customer ID etc.